# @Observable model changes not reflected in the View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Following is my sample implementation for testing `@Observable` feature in SwiftUI. It contains simple List View and detail View.

We can add objects to the list(and they are reflected in the View). We can go to detail View and edit name, description. But, these changes are not getting reflected in the previous screen(list).

Is this not the right way or should I use only `@EnvirnomentObject` variable to get the desired result?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ModelOne
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(){
                ForEach(model.items,id: \.id){
                    item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)){
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text(item.name).lineLimit(1)
                            Text(item.description).lineLimit(1)
                        }.onAppear {
                            print("\(item.name)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("List", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: AddItem(buttonAction: {
                    let newItem = Items()
                    newItem.name = "Empty"
                    newItem.description = "Empty"
                    self.model.items.append(newItem)
                }))
        }
    }
}

struct AddItem: View {
    var buttonAction: (()->Void)
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
            self.buttonAction()
        }){
            Text("Add")
        }
    }
}

class ModelOne: ObservableObject{
    @Published var items: [Items] = []
}

class Items: Identifiable{
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
}
```

Detailed View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Items
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField(item.name, text: $item.name)
            TextField(item.description, text: $item.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use @ EnvirnomentObject to reflect changes everywhere

Comment: @Lu_ I understand that we can use @ EnvirnomentObject but it should be possible even with Observable and ObsesrvedObjects. Just want to know why change in item.name, item.description is not changing Text View in list screen.

Comment: Tour item in DetailView should be a Binding for SwiftUI to know that changes made in this view influence ContentView

Comment: I tried adding @Binding in the detailView. It does not complile. It randomly throws error in previous screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` in `ContentView` is observing `model` - it isn't observing the items inside the rows, so an update to a specific `Items` doesn't trigger an update of `body` in `ContentView`.

The simplest way to address this is to move the row into its own `struct` that is observing the item.  That way when the item changes, the view in the row will be updated:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: ModelOne
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(){
                ForEach(model.items,id: \.id){
                    item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)){
                        Row(item:item)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("List", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: AddItem(buttonAction: {
                    let newItem = Items()
                    newItem.name = "Empty"
                    newItem.description = "Empty"
                    self.model.items.append(newItem)
                }))
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {

    @ObservedObject var item: Items

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(item.name).lineLimit(1)
                Text(item.description).lineLimit(1)
            }.onAppear {
                print("\(self.item.name)")  
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Haven’t had time to test this, but I think your type of “Array“ isn’t changing and therefore not triggering the publisher.  Also, your observing a single item in the detail view, but publishing changes on the “array“and I don’t believe that will work.

Try passing your observed model to the detailed view and an additional parameter for the specific item.